# Why is necessary to have OSPP files?

Tags: microsoft-office, office365, xml, vbscript, software-activation

I'm using Windows 8 and Microsoft Office 365.

When I go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16 there are 4 files:

- OSPP.HTM
- OSPP.VBS
- OSPPREARM.EXE
- SLERROR.XML

Why is this necessary to be on my computer (many sources on the internet don't give an answer to what they're doing)

What will happen if I delete them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Why are these files on my computer?

**OSPP.HTM/OSPP.VBS**

These files are use to [Reset Office 365 ProPlus 2013 and/or 2016 activation state](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/odsupport/2015/05/01/how-to-reset-an-office-365-install-to-the-initial-activationinstall-state/):

> To remove the Office 365 license, you must run two cscript command
>   lines. The command lines are:
>
> 1. Run `C:\program files <x86>\Microsoft office\office15>cscript ospp.vbs /dstatus`
> 2. Make note of value for “Last 5 characters of installed product key”
> 3. Run
>
>    `C:\program files <x86>\Microsoft office\office15>cscript ospp.vbs /unpkey:"Last 5 of installed product key"`
>
>    For example:
>
>    `C:\program files <x86>\Microsoft office\office15>cscript ospp.vbs unpkey:WB222`

**OSPPREARM.EXE**

This file is used to [Extend Your Office 2013/365 Trial to 180 Days](https://www.howtogeek.com/148347/how-to-extend-your-office-2013365-trial-to-180-days/):

> It is possible to ‘rearm’ the trial version of the software five times
>   – essentially giving you six 30-day trial periods, or 180 days in
>   total.
>
> While there are various tools that can be downloaded that can do this
>   job for you, there’s no need – everything you require is already
>   available to you. The only thing you need to remember is to run
>   through the rearming process before you trial periods run out; make
>   sure you do it on the thirtieth day of the trial.
>
> Navigate direct to `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft
>   Shared\OfficeSoftwareProtectionPlatform` or `C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OfficeSoftwareProtectionPlatform`
>   and type `OSPPREARM.EXE`

**SLERROR.XML**

This is a file containing [Activation Error Messages](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_install-mso_windows8/unable-to-open-office-home-student-2013/a841775b-0205-4e9f-a2eb-2688837b7253):

```
<err0xC004B001>The activation server determined that the license is invalid.</err0xC004B001>
<err0xC004B007>The activation server reported that the computer could not connect to the activation server.</err0xC004B007>
<err0xC004B008>The activation server determined that the product could not be activated.</err0xC004B008>
<err0xC004B010>The activation server determined that required business token entry cannot be found.</err0xC004B010>
<err0xC004B011>The activation server determined that your computer clock time is not correct. You must correct your clock before you can activate.</err0xC004B011>
<err0xC004B100>The activation server determined that the product could not be activated.</err0xC004B100>
<err0xC004C001>The activation server determined the specified product key is invalid.</err0xC004C001>
<err0xC004C002>The activation server determined there is a problem with the specified product key.</err0xC004C002>
<err0xC004C003>The activation server determined the specified product key has been blocked.</err0xC004C003>
```

---

#### What will happen if I delete them?

Don't do that. You will break your Office installation.